# Redux , Getting all the state instead of the state that i passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having a wierd issue in `react-redux` , i am getting all the state instead of the state that i passed 
this is my code:

**Action.js**

```
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

const DATA_URL = "LINK TO API";
export const GET_DATA ='GET_DATA';
export const LIVE_DATA = 'LIVE_DATA';
const parseData= arr => arr.reverse().map((i)=>([i[0],i[1],i[3],i[4],i[2],i[5]]))

export const getData = () => dispatch =>{
   fetch(DATA_URL).then(res => res.json())
                  .then(data => dispatch({
                    type:GET_DATA,
                    payload:parseData(data)
                  }
))
}
export const getLive = () => dispatch => {
  var checkTime=0;
 const socket = socketIOClient('http://localhost:3001');
       socket.on("candle",(res)=>{
            if(checkTime <= res[0]){
               checkTime = res[0];
               dispatch({
                 type:LIVE_DATA,
                 payload:res
               })
             }
          })
}
```

**api.js**

```
import {GET_DATA,LIVE_DATA} from '../actions/index';
const INITIAL_STATE = {all:[],live:[]}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_DATA:
      return Object.assign({},state,{all:action.payload})
    case LIVE_DATA:
    return Object.assign({},state,{live:action.payload})
    default:
     return state;
  }
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import all from './api';
import live from './api';
const reducers = combineReducers({
candle:all,
livedata:live
});
export default reducers;
```

As you can see i am passing `all` to `candle` and `live` to `livedata`

But in my Reduxdevtools i can access everything from both candle and livedata as you can see in the screen shot

[image]

This is how i dispatch the action on my component

**App.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.candle.all,
  live: state.livedata.live
})
```

Can someone tell me what need to be changed so i could be able to access only

`live` in the `livedata` state and `all` only in the `candle` state

Thank you

Comment: Share your action creator and actions file. Probably, your constants has the same strings values.

Comment: @DenysKotsur i did update my question with the code for the actioncreator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened because you're accessing the same reducer but with different names. You should create separate reducer for each.

Like this:

**candleReducer.js**

```
import {GET_DATA} from '../actions';

const INITIAL_STATE = { all:[] }

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_DATA:
      return Object.assign({},state,{all:action.payload})
    default:
     return state;
  }
}
```

**liveReducer.js**

```
import {LIVE_DATA} from '../actions';

const INITIAL_STATE = { live:[] }

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LIVE_DATA:
     return Object.assign({},state,{ live:action.payload })
    default:
     return state;
  }
}
```

and then import them into combine reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import all from './candleReducer';
import live from './liveReducer';
const reducers = combineReducers({
    candle:all,
    livedata:live
});
export default reducers;
```

Comment: Hello thank for taking the time to take a look at my code , There is no way i can put them in the same file and separete the state ?

Comment: sure you can do it as @Coogle said. If it's ok with your logic you can just split your state.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same reducer function for two 'part' of the state.

In your case you are duplicating the same logic in two parts, so the same reducer is called and it react to the same actions and update two entries in the state with the same logic.

You should consider to write two separate reducer for candle and livedata, so each of them will react to a specific action and modify correct entry in the state.

But if candle and livedata are releated to the same domain you should consider to put in one reducer and of course in one section of state, so you will end up in this situation

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  apiData:liveAndCandleReducer,
});
```

In apiData you will have

```
{
   all:[],
   live: [],
}
```

It's totally up to you and your application logic.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answear the question , i think i will put them in the same reducer and use your aproach